# Vectorisation of for-loop with data dependecy

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, optimization, vectorization

I have an implementation of BiCCG (Conjugate Gradient) based matrix solver which also accounts for periodicity. It happens to be the case that the implementation is compute intensive and the loop is not auto vectorized because of the dependency problem. I explored a bit and it seems a red-black gauss seidel algorithm is more efficiently parallelizable than a vanilla version(which also has a similar dependency problem).

Can this loop/algorithm be changed such that it can be efficiently vectorised?

```
 // FORWARD
        #pragma omp for schedule(static, nx/NTt)
        for (i=1; i<=nx; i++) for (j=1; j<=ny; j++) for (k=1; k<=nz; k++)
        {


            dummy = res_sparse_s[i][j][k];

                                           dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][7] * RLL[i-1][j][k];
            if (PeriodicBoundaryX && i==nx)dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][8] * RLL[1  ][j][k];


                                            dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][2] * RLL[i][j-1][k];
            if (PeriodicBoundaryY && j==ny) dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][3] * RLL[i][1  ][k];


                                            dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][4] * RLL[i][j][k-1];
            if (PeriodicBoundaryZ && k==nz) dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][5] * RLL[i][j][1  ];


            RLL[i][j][k] = dummy / h_sparse_s[i][j][k];
        }
```

P.S. RLL for any iteration i,j,k incorporates the updated "RLL" at i-1 , j-1 and k-1 through the variable dummy. Also now the loop is only being broken down in the x direction using the directive `schedule(static, nx/NTt)` where NTt is just a macro for the available number of threads. Can it be broken down in all directions using the directive `collapse`?

------- MAJOR EDIT --------------------------
following Ajay's answer here is a minimum working example

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<omp.h>

typedef double lr;

#define nx 4
#define ny 4
#define nz 4

void
print3dmatrix(double a[nx+2][ny+2][nz+2])
{
    for(int i=1; i<= nx; i++) {
        for(int j=1; j<= ny; j++) {
            for(int k=1; k<= nz; k++) {
                printf("%f ", a[i][j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int 
main()
{

    double a[nx+2][ny+2][nz+2];
    double b[nx+2][ny+2][nz+2];

    srand(3461833726);


    // matrix filling 
    // b is just a copy of a
    for(int i=0; i< nx+2; i++) for(int j=0; j< ny+2; j++) for(int k=0; k< nz+2; k++)
    {
        a[i][j][k] = rand() % 5;
        b[i][j][k] = a[i][j][k];
    }

    // loop 1
    //#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(1)
    for(int i=1; i<= nx; i++) for(int j=1; j<= ny; j++) for(int k=1; k<= nz; k++)
    {
        a[i][j][k] = -1*a[i-1][j][k] - 1*a[i][j-1][k] -1 * a[i][j][k-1] + 4 * a[i][j][k];
    }

    print3dmatrix(a);
    printf("******************************\n");

    // loop 2
    //#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(1)
    for(int i=1; i<= nx; i++) 
        for(int j=1; j<= ny; j++)
            // #pragma omp simd
            for(int m=j+1; m<= j+nz; m++)
            {
                b[i][j][m-j] = -1*b[i-1][j][m-j] - 1*b[i][j-1][m-j] -1 * b[i][j][m-j-1] + 4 * b[i][j][m-j];
            }

    print3dmatrix(b);
    printf("=========================\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Key observations-

1. Matrix a is filled with random numbers in between 0 to 5 and loop 1 is non transformed original loop whereas loop 2 is a transformed loop
2. The transformed loop has been skewed so as to remove dependency.
3. After the operation matrix a and b are same if run without the openmp parallelization
4. if open mp is deployed the answers change (because of maybe race conditions) [ loop is not paralellisable irrespective of where the pragma is placed ]
5. if `#pragma omp simd` is used to enforce vectorisation of innermost loop it fails.

Comment: Did you try some loop skew transformations to remove the dependencies?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya i am quite new to this field but till now what i have looked at was a use case of gauss seidel vectorisation using red-black method and wave transformation. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: I am not aware of your particular use case. I know nothing about matrix solvers or BiCCG. I just know about parallelizing (or vectorizing) general loops. From your question I understand that loop carried dependencies are inhibiting vectorization. There are a set of affine transformations which when applied to the loop can remove the dependences and let you create a schedule which can use vectorization. You can read about "affine transformations on loop nests". Maybe it can be of some help. Sorry I am not familiar with your specific problem.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya thanks for the pointers i would look into this. Well I guess you won't need a deep perspective of the algorithm in total but specific to this loop you can see for a iterative 3D matrix (i, j, k) the value at `RLL[i][j][k]` is dependent on the value of `RLL[i-1][j][k]` , `RLL[i][j-1][k]` and `RLL[i][j][k-1]` through the variable dummy. Here lies the dependency and possible race conditions which making the compiler run this loop in serial.

Comment: okay, this dependences can be represented as `[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]`. My guess is if you apply the transformation `k -> k + i`, the third element in all the dependence vectors will become zero. In that case you will be able to vectorize the inner most loop (that should buy you a lot of parallelism). How to exactly apply the transformation, you can look up. You basically have to change the loop iterations so that the inner most loop doesn't have any dependence. I will try to write an answer with a simple example.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic problem of loop carried dependences. Every iteration of yours depend on some other iterations (to have finished), and the only way it can be scheduled is thus serially.

But that is just because how your loop is written.

You mention that `R[i][j][k]` depends on the calculation of `R[i-1][j][k]`, `R[i][j-1][k]`, `R[i][j][k-1]`. I see three dependences here -

1. [1, 0, 0]
2. [0, 1, 0]
3. [0, 0, 1]

I hope this representation is intuitive.

For your present scenario, dependence 1) and 2) are not an issue because there is a `0` in `k` and there are `1` in `i`/`j`, which means that the iteration does not depend on previous iterations of k to complete for these two dependences.

The problem is because of 3). Since there is a `1` in `k`, every iteration depends on it's previous iteration. If somehow we were able to bring a number `>0` in `i`/`j` we would be done. A loop skew transformation lets us do exactly the same.

A 3D example is slightly difficult to understand. So let's look at 2D example with `i` and `j`.

Suppose - `R[i][j]` depends on `R[i-1][j]` and `R[i][j-1]`. We have the same problem.

If we have to represent this in a picture it looks like this -

```
. <- . <- .
     |    |
     v    v
. <- . <- .
     |    |
     v    v
.    .    .
```

In this picture, every point represents and iteration `(i,j)` and the arrows originating from each point, point to the iteration it depends on. It is clear to see why we cannot parallelize the inner most loop here.

But suppose we did the skewing as -

```
        .
       /|   
      / |
    .   .
   /|  /|
  / | / |
.   .   . 
   /|    
  / |  
.   .     


.
```

And if you draw the same arrows as in the above picture (I cannot draw diagonal arrows in the ASCII art).

You will see that all the arrows are pointing downwards i.e. they atleast go on iteration down, which means you can parallelize the horizontal loop.

Now say your new loop dimensions are `y` (outer loop) and `x` (inner loop),

your original variables `i`, `j` will be

`j = x` and `i = x - y`

Your loop body thus becomes -

```
for ( y = 0; y < j_max + i_max; y++) 
    for ( x = 0; x < j_max; x++)
        R_dash[y][x] = R_dash[y-1][x-1] + R_dash[y-1][x];
```

Where `R_dash` is the skewed domain and has a one to one mapping to `R`

You will see that both `R_dash[y-1][x-1]` and `R_dash[y-1][x]` will be computed in some previous iteration of y. And hence you can completely parallelize the x loop.

The transformation applied here is

`i -> i, j -> i + j`.

You can similarly work it out for 3 dimensions.

For further understanding on how affine transformations work and how they can be used to introduce parallelism, you can see these [lecture notes](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~mstrout/CS553Fall06/slides/lecture30-looptransform.pdf).

Comment: thanks for the elegant explanation and the link as well. Looks like there is lot to learn on this topic. I will give it a shot and update the post here.

Comment: @datapanda sure. You can try reading it out and my guess is for your 3D case, a similar skew in `k` will be required. Also if you are wondering what `R_dash`, it is just another way of looking at `R`. It can be implemented as a macro - Something like `#define R_dash(x, x) R[x-y][x]` and use it as `R_dash(..., ...)` instead of `R_dash[...][...]`

Comment: does this still hold true for those specific if cases (see in the original post) where `R[i][j][k]` depends on `R[1][j][k]`, `R[i][1][k]` and `R[i][j][1]` ?

Comment: @datapanda constant index ones are not really a problem (for parallelization). Think in the k loop. You calculated the first value and then rest of the values depend on it. All the rest of the iterations can be parallelized, right? These type of dependences usually raise another issue of cache misses. But that is not the problem we are trying to solve here.

Comment: regarding cache misses i do understand that the loop transformations will change the way in which the data is accessed which is not the same sequence in which it is stored (for eg. row major in C) but as a first cut I will try to see what performance gain I will get and for now I will live with the cache misses.

Comment: @datapanda the cache misses can also be dealt with by laying your data in the skewed way, so that the accesses will be in order. Yes, it will not be perfect. Then you can perform tiling too to get the best out it. There are a lot of optimizations. But I think a standard compiler should be able to do it for you with adequate optimization levels. Try not to optimize most things by hand.

Comment: coming back to the implementation, it seems trivial for a 2d loop and i read up a lot on loop transformations. But i am still struggling with the implementation regarding a 3d ( 3 level loop nesting ). From your discussion it seems only the inner loop needs to be **skewed** w.r.t outer loop/loops. What i am not getting is the latter part. Does it needs to be skewed with both i and j loops.
P.S. also i guess in your discussion you picked `j` for the x direction `i` for the y direction

Comment: @datapanda in the case of 3 dimensions think of it as a one big loop outside a 2d case. Just apply the exact technique you did in 2d and your inner loop gets vectorizable. The outer dimension does not add any complexity. To answer your question, you need to skew only using one of i or j. Also yes, I picked i for y and j for x. Pardon me if I broke the convention somewhere and wrote the other way.

Comment: so you mean to say (corresponding to the loop in my question) if i skew the innermost loop `k` wrt the `j` loop keeping `i` as it is then it should do the work ?  Ofcourse the last two indexes for the matrices inside the loop will change accordingly.

Comment: it didnt worked. see a minimum workable code (updated the question) which you can try running