# Loop transformation for data dependence and parallelization

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, optimization, openmp

I have a nested `for` loop for iterating over a three dimensional space (one for each dimension). The nested loop forms a part of a stencil based matrix solver which has a operation with data dependence. I have gone through lot of links/online material going into the details of **loop transformations** and it seems like loop skewing can help me. Though it is pretty straight forward for a 2d grid (consisting of two loop nests) i find it bit difficult to extend to 3d. The loop looks like this.

```
# pragma omp parallel num_threads(NTt) default(none) private(i,j,k, mythread, dummy) shared(STA,res_sparse_s,COEFF,p_sparse_s, ap_sparse_s,h_sparse_s,RLL, pipi_sparse, normres_sparse, riri_sparse,riri_sparse2,noemer_sparse, nx, ny, nz, nv, PeriodicBoundaryX, PeriodicBoundaryY, PeriodicBoundaryZ)
{

    mythread  = omp_get_thread_num();//0

    // loop 1
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:pipi_sparse)
    for (i=1; i<=nx; i++) for (j=1; j<=ny; j++) for (k=1; k<=nz; k++)
    {                    
        dummy = COEFF[i][j][k][6] * p_sparse_s[i][j][k];

        if (PeriodicBoundaryX && i == 1)  dummy += COEFF[i][j][k][0] * p_sparse_s[nx ][j][k];
        else                              dummy += COEFF[i][j][k][0] * p_sparse_s[i-1][j][k];

        if (PeriodicBoundaryX && i == nx) dummy += COEFF[i][j][k][1] * p_sparse_s[1  ][j][k];
        else                              dummy += COEFF[i][j][k][1] * p_sparse_s[i+1][j][k];

        if (PeriodicBoundaryY && j == 1)  dummy += COEFF[i][j][k][2] * p_sparse_s[i][ny ][k];
        else                              dummy += COEFF[i][j][k][2] * p_sparse_s[i][j-1][k];

        if (PeriodicBoundaryY && j == ny) dummy += COEFF[i][j][k][3] * p_sparse_s[i][  1][k];
        else                              dummy += COEFF[i][j][k][3] * p_sparse_s[i][j+1][k];

        if (PeriodicBoundaryZ && k == 1)  dummy += COEFF[i][j][k][4] * p_sparse_s[i][j][nz ];
        else                              dummy += COEFF[i][j][k][4] * p_sparse_s[i][j][k-1];


        if (PeriodicBoundaryZ && k == nz) dummy += COEFF[i][j][k][5] * p_sparse_s[i][j][  1];
        else                              dummy += COEFF[i][j][k][5] * p_sparse_s[i][j][k+1];

        ap_sparse_s[i][j][k] = dummy;
        pipi_sparse += p_sparse_s[i][j][k] * ap_sparse_s[i][j][k];
    }


    // loop 2
        // FORWARD
        #pragma omp for schedule(static, nx/NTt)
        for (i=1; i<=nx; i++) for (j=1; j<=ny; j++) for (k=1; k<=nz; k++)
        {


            dummy = res_sparse_s[i][j][k];

                                           dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][7] * RLL[i-1][j][k];
            if (PeriodicBoundaryX && i==nx)dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][8] * RLL[1  ][j][k];


                                            dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][2] * RLL[i][j-1][k];
            if (PeriodicBoundaryY && j==ny) dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][3] * RLL[i][1  ][k];


                                            dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][4] * RLL[i][j][k-1];
            if (PeriodicBoundaryZ && k==nz) dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][5] * RLL[i][j][1  ];


            RLL[i][j][k] = dummy / h_sparse_s[i][j][k];
        }

    // loop 3
        // BACKWARD
        #pragma omp for schedule(static, nx/NTt)
        for (i=nx; i>=1;i--) for (j=ny; j>=1;j--) for (k=nz; k>=1;k--)
        {
            dummy = RLL[i][j][k]*h_sparse_s[i][j][k];

            if (PeriodicBoundaryX && i==1) dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][7] * RLL[nx ][j][k];
                                           dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][8] * RLL[i+1][j][k];

            if (PeriodicBoundaryY && j==1) dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][2] * RLL[i][ny ][k];
                                           dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][3] * RLL[i][j+1][k];

            if (PeriodicBoundaryZ && k==1) dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][4] * RLL[i][j][nz ];
                                           dummy -= COEFF[i][j][k][5] * RLL[i][j][k+1];


            RLL[i][j][k] =  dummy  / h_sparse_s[i][j][k];
        }

}
```

- Loop 1 -> Data dependence of `[i][j][k]` on `[i+1][i-1][j-1][j+1][k-1][k+1]` although the values of `p_sparse_s` are read-only
- Loop 2 -> Data dependence of `[i][j][k]` on `[i-1][j-1][k-1]`
- Loop 3 -> Data dependence of `[i][j][k]` on `[i+1][j+1][k+1]`

### EDIT

`COEFF[i][j][k][NUM]` are just generic coefficients (some constant numbers) defined for each point in the 3d space. Since there are 9 such coefficients corresponding to neighboring points hence `COEFF[][][][0], COEFF[][][][1] .... COEFF[][][][8]`and like that.

### EDIT

find a small code below that has a data dependence. I have tried to skew the inner k loop with respect to the i and j loop so that the k loop can be vectorised. Problem is the code gives absolutely correct answers when running in serial and gives some weird answers if I enforce parallelism or if I enforce vectorisation of the inner loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<omp.h>

typedef double lr;

#define nx 4
#define ny 4
#define nz 4

void
print3dmatrix(double a[nx+2][ny+2][nz+2])
{
    for(int i=1; i<= nx; i++) {
        for(int j=1; j<= ny; j++) {
            for(int k=1; k<= nz; k++) {
                printf("%f ", a[i][j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int 
main()
{

    double a[nx+2][ny+2][nz+2];
    double b[nx+2][ny+2][nz+2];

    srand(3461833726);


    // matrix filling 
    // b is just a copy of a
    for(int i=0; i< nx+2; i++) for(int j=0; j< ny+2; j++) for(int k=0; k< nz+2; k++)
    {
        a[i][j][k] = rand() % 5;
        b[i][j][k] = a[i][j][k];
    }

    // loop 1
    //#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(1)
    for(int i=1; i<= nx; i++) for(int j=1; j<= ny; j++) for(int k=1; k<= nz; k++)
    {
        a[i][j][k] = -1*a[i-1][j][k] - 1*a[i][j-1][k] -1 * a[i][j][k-1] + 4 * a[i][j][k];
    }

    print3dmatrix(a);
    printf("******************************\n");

    // loop 2
    //#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(1)
    for(int i=1; i<= nx; i++) 
        for(int j=1; j<= ny; j++)
            // #pragma omp simd
            for(int m=j+1; m<= j+nz; m++)
            {
                b[i][j][m-j] = -1*b[i-1][j][m-j] - 1*b[i][j-1][m-j] -1 * b[i][j][m-j-1] + 4 * b[i][j][m-j];
            }

    print3dmatrix(b);
    printf("=========================\n");

    return 0;
}
```

see - [loop skewing for vectorisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580852/vectorisation-of-for-loop-with-data-dependecy/51582405?noredirect=1#comment90428352_51582405)

Comment: Are you sure it is correct to use 1-based array indexing?

Comment: @WeatherVane pardon me , i didn't get the question. which line are you refering to? I mean while operating serially I don't have any problems with these loops.

Comment: I mean the loops like `for (i=1; i<=nx; i++) for (j=1; j<=ny; j++) for (k=1; k<=nz; k++)` followed by `dummy = COEFF[i][j][k][6] * p_sparse_s[i][j][k];` You don't show how `COEFF` or `p_sparse_s` are defined, meaning whether they have enough elements to index by `nx` etc.

Comment: @weathervane coeff matrices are set of 9 coefficients for a given i,j,k point in the matrix. those are just some constant numbers.`p_sparse_s` is also a 3d matrix defined for each point in the physical space.

Comment: @WeatherVane edited the question.

Comment: `COEFF[][][][0], COEFF[][][][1] .... COEFF[][][][9]` requires **10 such coefficients**, not 9.

Comment: oops .. typo. they go till `COEFF[][][][8]`

Comment: I'm a little confused by loop 2 (and 3, it's the same thing really), since you have dependence on `[i-1,j-1,k-1]` and potentially 
(seems you can turn that off, in which case this issue does not appear) periodic boundary conditions, this suggests that the equations here are implicit. Are you sure your approach makes sense in the periodic case?

Comment: Speaking of loops 2 and 3, the periodic boundary condition also appears wrong, you check if say `i==nx` and then set it to `1` in the first loop, but the dependence is on `i-1`, so the issue should be with `i==1` which should loop around to `i=nx`. (And yes, this 1-based index thing you have here is a little odd for C. )

Comment: @Qubit regarding 1 based index the matrices(all three D matrices) have dimensions of `nx+2`, `ny+2` and `nz+2` and then the 0 and the nx+1 (similarly for y and z direction as well are just **ghost cells** which are not solver for in the matrix solver but are there for enforcing certain boundary conditions. I will update the question with a small code that folks can give it a try.